# How to get another address in Remix IDE

Tags: solidity, remix, addresses

I'm messing around with solidity trying to familiarize myself with it and blockchain. So I have this simple dragon selling game. A user (targaryen) registers with a username and gets some dragons, which he can later sell to another user. Here is my code:

```
contract Messenger {
    struct Targaryen
    {
        bool registered;
        string uname;
        uint coins;
        Dragon[] dragons;
    }

    mapping(address => Targaryen) public targaryens;
    
    function register(string calldata uname) external returns(bool)
    {
        Targaryen storage t = targaryens[msg.sender];
        if(!t.registered)
        {
            t.registered = true;
            t.uname = uname;
            t.coins = 100;
            t.dragons = defaultDragons;

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    function sellDragon(address buyer, uint dragon) public returns (bool)
    {
        if(targaryens[msg.sender].registered && targaryens[buyer].registered) //Here it just returns false
        {
            if (dragon >= targaryens[msg.sender].dragons.length) return false;
            if (targaryens[msg.sender].dragons[dragon].rarity > targaryens[buyer].coins) return false;
            
            Dragon memory toSell = targaryens[msg.sender].dragons[dragon];
            targaryens[msg.sender].coins += toSell.rarity;
            
            removeDragon(msg.sender, dragon);
            
            targaryens[buyer].dragons.push(toSell);
            targaryens[buyer].coins -= toSell.rarity;
            
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

I'm using the Remix IDE. I deploy two of these contracts. I then register a user form each of these and then try to sell a dragon from one contract to the other. The targaryens mapping has only the user who owns the contract and the transaction fails.
There is clearly something I completely misunderstand about how contracts work. How can I do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Why you deploy same contract for each user? In your contract you already have mapping from address to Targaryen. Just register both users from same contract and try to sell in same contract as well.

Comment: But in the register function I use the msg.sender to get the sender address. If I register two users then the first one will register normally and the second one with return false since there is already a user registered with this address.